# Exporting to .ac file using io_scene_ac3d folder files

Tags: python, export, add-on

I'm trying to modify a Blender file object (aircraft instrument) then export to an .ac file for use in Flightgear. Error script follows below. I've enabled the ac3d folder contents in separate attempts for the directory folders as such:

/program files/blender foundation/blender/2.79/scripts/addons

/program files/blender foundation/blender/2.79/scripts/addons_contrib

I also tried enabling the addon within the Supported Level:Testing area

- Hardware: EliteBook 8770W laptop, Windows 10 Home, 10.0.17134, x64. Intel i7-3520M, 8GB ram, AMD Firepro M4000 1GB ram. 1920x1080x60
  Hertz.
- Blender software: v2.79
- io_scene_ac3d folder contents: _ init _.py, AC3D.py, export_ac3d.py, import_ac3d.py

When I try to export my Blender file to a .ac format, I receive the following red-lined errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\__init__.py", line 266, in execute
export_ac3d.ExportAC3D(self, context, **keywords)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\export_ac3d.py", line 115, in __init__
self.world.parse(self.ac_mats)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\AC3D.py", line 70, in parse
child.parse(ac_mats, str_pre + ' ')

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\AC3D.py", line 67, in parse
self._parse(ac_mats, str_pre)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\AC3D.py", line 136, in _parse
self._parseMesh(ac_mats)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\AC3D.py", line 141, in _parseMesh
self._parseMaterials(mesh, ac_mats)

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_ac3d\AC3D.py", line 183, in _parseMaterials
bl_im = bl_tex.image

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I'm not familiar enough with the Python/C++ language to determine the cause of the error. Can anyone provide me some hints on how to fix/correct the export feature? Is this export error within Blender settings/config or is the error within the .py import-export files?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: Apparently my export error was caused by an incorrect path for one of the texture files.